# How to extend the String class in a command line app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I primarily work in Rails and I'm using a command line data conversion gem, "[Mongify](http://mongify.com)" and I am stumped about how to extend core classes in a Ruby cli app.

I want to extend the String class with an `.is_date?` method to check whether a string can be converted to a `Date`.  I've got it working in the Rails Console,

I added a `string.rb` file to `lib/ext` with the following;

```
class String
  def is_date?
    begin
      return true if Date.parse(self)
      rescue
        #do nothing
    end
    return false
  end
end
```

Then in a Rails console I do a `require 'ext/string'` and it will work.
But I can't figure out how to get it to work in the Mongify cli app.  I copied string.rb into the lib folder of the gem and I've tried adding `require 'string'` to a number of different files in the gem, but I keep getting `undefined method` errors.
Can someone point me in the right direction?

Comment: can you use require in this file: https://github.com/anlek/mongify/blob/master/lib/mongify.rb then you can stick pry somewhere in your code to inspect the methods that are available at run time

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about you require it from `lib/mongify.rb` like so:

```
require 'string/extensions.rb'
```

And then put your code in `lib/string/extensions.rb`

Let us know the exact `undefined method` errors you're getting in case this isn't the solution.

Comment: Ok Ivan,  Did all that and here is the error it returns; 

(eval):80:in `block (2 levels) in parse': undefined method `is_date?' for "":String (NoMethodError)

Comment: Sorry, you'd have to provide the full code to see why your extension isn't being loaded. If you can do that I'd be happy to take a look.

Comment: Thanks Ivan, it turned out that I was changing code in the wrong gemset,  duh...  Your suggestion worked perfectly once I made it in the code that was executing!

Answer (score 1):

To help you with the debugging exercise that would give you the answer you need. Start by putting a breakpoint right before the place of the function call.

In the debugger, load the required document and then step past your breakpoint to the next one after the call has occurred.

Once you have this working, then start earlier in the stack trace – in a file that loaded before that one.  Keep moving backwards until you get to a sufficiently early part in the load process of the gem, and make that be the place you load your code.